# How to optimize $f(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^Mx_{i}y_{i}$, given that $\sum_{i=1}^Mx_i=a>0$, $\sum_{i=1}^My_i=b>0$, $x_i > 0,y_i> 0$ for all $i$.

Tags: inequality, optimization, convex-optimization

I need to optimize

$f(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^Mx_{i}y_{i}$

such that

$\sum_{i=1}^Mx_i=a>0$

$\sum_{i=1}^My_i=b>0$

$x_i > 0,y_i> 0$ for all $i$.

1. I have a feeling that the point $x_i=\frac{a}{M}$ and $y_i=\frac{b}{M}$ achieves the optimal, but haven't found a way to prove/disprove it.
2. Can this be formulated as a standard convex optimization problem?

Comment: "optimize" is "maximise" or "minimise"?

Comment: Are you sure that it is not $x_i \ge 0$ and $y_i \ge 0$? It is easier when the feasible set is compact.

Comment: Thanks, for both maximize and minimize,  and $x_i$ and $y_i$ are strictly larger than 0.

Answer (score 3):

$$0<\sum_{i=1}^Mx_iy_i\leq\sum_{i=1}^Mx_i\sum_{i=1}^My_i=ab$$
For $x\rightarrow(a,0,...,0)$ and $y\rightarrow(0,b,0,...,0)$ we get the infimum

and for $x\rightarrow(a,0,...,0)$ and $y\rightarrow(b,0,...,0)$ we get the supremum.

Comment: @user2008790 What do you think about my answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot, understood, and I am just wondering how did you get it (although it is easy to check). Can this problem be formulated as a standard optimization problem?

Comment: @user2008790 What do you mean under words "a standard optimization problem"?

Comment: In a comment to the question, OP wrote "$x_i$ and $y_i$ are strictly larger than zero".

Comment: @mlc The maximum and the minimum does not exist. I don't see any problem.

Comment: @MIchael: no problem, except that the OP is not consistent.